# ValueError: math domain error whilst using inverse sine rule

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import math

X=(math.asin(10*math.sin(math.radians(15)))/10*(180/math.pi))

print(X)
```

Whilst experimenting with using the sine rule it comes up with a ValueError: math domain error, however the code below does not bring up this issue.

```
import math

X=(math.asin(math.sin(math.radians(15)))*180/math.pi)

print(X)
```

I am aware that by multiplying by 10 then dividing by 10 equals 1 so the effects cancel out but I am unsure why an issue is being raised.

Comment: You're multiplying the argument to `asin` by 10, which puts it outside the range `-1,1`. Your subsequent division by ten etc. is outside the `math.asin(...)` parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to debug the issue I always recommend to split the equation to smaller parts

Using following code you will see that issue coming in asin function because your argument is ~2.5 which is out of -1;1 range

```
import math

sin_val = math.sin(math.radians(15))
asin_val = math.asin(10*sin_val)
X = asin_val/10*(180/math.pi)
```